# Tricky fault in data validator code in JS

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, input

I have a very tricky fault in data validator code in JS, as I need to make a function to review all HTML user Form in the page as I will have to feed in number of inputs to check, the code just work fine if the first input contain an error but it didn't work at all when the 1st input contain no error. I checked the loop and if conditions separately and I couldn't see the error and it appear that  I will need a fresh eyes the code of the whole page is here:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
#ballon{
border:solid 1px #c0c0c0;
background-color:yellow;
font-size:11px;
font-family:verdana;
padding:5px;
position:absolute;
z-index:2;
visibility:hidden;
}

</style>
<script language="javascript">

var bstatus="off";
var Errmsg="";

//1)function show error message ballon and used by checkall(x) function below
 function Showmsg(error,Frm){
 if(!document.getElementById("ballon")){//to check if the ballon div is created or not
 var ballon=document.createElement("div")  
 ballon.id="ballon";
  document.body.appendChild(ballon); }
  else{ 
  var ballon=document.getElementById("ballon");
   }

 if(bstatus=="on"){//to check if the ballon is visible or not
 ballon.style.top=Frm.offsetTop +"px";
 ballon.style.left=Frm.offsetLeft+ Frm.offsetWidth + 5 +"px";
 ballon.innerHTML=error;    
}else{  
 bstatus="on"; 
 ballon.style.visibility="visible";
 ballon.style.top=Frm.offsetTop +"px";
 ballon.style.left=Frm.offsetLeft+ Frm.offsetWidth + 5 +"px";     ballon.innerHTML=error; 
 } 
 }//end of function

 //2)hide the error message ballon and used by checkall() function below
  function Hidemsg(){
bstatus="off";  Errmsg=""; 
var ballon=document.getElementById("ballon");
ballon.innerHTML=""; 
 ballon.style.visibility="hidden";

 }

 function write(number){//to check where we are in the looping
 var gad=document.getElementById("gad");
 gad.innerHTML=gad.outerHTML+ number;
 }

 //3) check all function to review if values of the input forms  

  function checkall(x){
  for(i=0;i<x;i++){//to loop on all input in form we need to check
  var Formtype=" ";  
  var Myform=" ";
  Myform=document.forms[0].elements[i];
  Formtype=Myform.getAttribute("title");

  switch(Formtype){ 
  case "txt":
  var value2check=/^[a-zA-Z]+$/; 
  var Errmode="Please enter text only"; break;
   case "num":
  var value2check=/^[0-9]+$/; 
  var Errmode="Please enter number only";break;
  case "both":
  var value2check=/^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/;
  var Errmode="No simples are allowed only alphanumerical values"; break;
   case "email":
  var value2check= /^[\w\-\.\+]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]{2,4}$/; 
   var Errmode="Please enter valid Email"; break;
   case "domain":
  var value2check= /((?:https?\:\/\/|www\.)(?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)*[-a-z0-9]+.*)/i; 
  var Errmode="Please enter valid URL"; break;
  default: 
  var value2check="";
  }//end of switch

  if(Myform.value.length!=0 || Myform.value!=""){//to check if the form value is not null
   if(Myform.value.match(value2check)){ 
       Errmsg="";  Hidemsg(); 
   write(Myform.name+" "+i+" "+bstatus+"<br>");//to test the where we are in the loop
  }else{
    Errmsg=Errmode;       Showmsg(Errmsg,Myform);     break;
    } //end of inner If condition
   }else{   
    Errmsg="Please fill in blank data";
Showmsg(Errmsg,Myform); break; 
}//end of if statment 
      }//end of for loop
    }//end of checkall function


    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <form action="" method="post">
     Name of the New table:<input name="tblname" type="text"  id="elem" placeholder="Enter tablename" title="txt"><br><br>
     Number of columns:&nbsp;<input type="text" name="colnumb" placeholder="colnum" title="num"   value="" size="3" maxlength="3" lenght="3"><br><br>   Table Type:&nbsp;<select name="Tbltype"><option value="MyISAM"selected>MyISAM<option value="InnoDB">InnoDB<option value="CSV">CSV<option value="ARCHIVE">ARCHIVE</select><br><br>

     <input type="button" name="next" value="Next >>" onclick="checkall(2)">

     </form> 
     <div id="gad"></div>
     </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: will try to enter valid txt in the first input and it will not work at all on the remaining inputs in the form, while if there is non valid data it will work as planned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in Hidemsg, it was trying to hide the "ballon" when it was not on screen and causing an error, just add a test to see ballon exists before running the code

```
function Hidemsg() {
    bstatus = "off";
    Errmsg = "";
    var ballon = document.getElementById("ballon");
    if(ballon)
    {
        ballon.innerHTML = "";
        ballon.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }

}
```

fiddle http://fiddle.jshell.net/leighking2/5u7oyvqz/

Comment: if this issue is now closed for you you can mark this as the answer, cheers